# Define RabbitMQ policies in configuration file

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I'd like to define mirroring for all my queues by default. I currently have to [use `rabbitmqctl`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#examples) once the node is up:

```sh
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all"}'
```

If one of my nodes fail, I'd have to remember to re-execute that code on restart.

Is there a way to automatically configure my node to use mirrored queues?

Answer (score 31):

Policy CAN be specified in a definition file, which can be referred to from your config file.

Example of how I have set a specific policy (not sure if ha can be specified in policy):

**/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config**

```
[
{rabbit,
    [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.8}]
},
{rabbitmq_management,
    [{listener, [{port, 15672}]},
     {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json"},
     {http_log_dir, "/var/log/rabbitmq/management_http.log"}]
}
].
```

**/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json**

```
{       "users":[
            {"name":"rabbot","password_hash":"Cvse5iGOg20UqUq7Za9D1tatOJnMVDru4GHtxqc02g7zj5ur","tags":""},
            {"name":"rabnet","password_hash":"CqqG2fwvH6xz64NpibGJx2M7ZCyFnR1BQBM+C0KH2qRPmVxF","tags":"administrator"}],
    "vhosts":[
            {"name":"/"}],
    "permissions":[
            {"user":"viabot","vhost":"VIA","configure":".*","write":".*","read":".*"},
            {"user":"vianet","vhost":"VIA","configure":".*","write":".*","read":".*"}],
    "parameters":[],
    "policies":[
            {"vhost":"VIA","name":"DLX","pattern":".*","apply-to":"queues","definition":{"dead-letter-exchange":"dead_letter"},"priority":0}
            ],
    "queues":[
            {"name":"store_to_es","vhost":"VIA","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{}},
            {"name":"store_to_mongodb","vhost":"VIA","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{}}
            ],
    "exchanges":[
            {"name":"data_incoming","vhost":"VIA","type":"fanout","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"internal":false,"arguments":{}},
            {"name":"sms_incoming","vhost":"VIA","type":"fanout","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"internal":false,"arguments":{}}
            ],
    "bindings":[
            {"source":"data_incoming","vhost":"VIA","destination":"store_to_es","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"","arguments":{}},
            {"source":"sms_incoming","vhost":"VIA","destination":"store_to_mongodb","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"","arguments":{}}
    ]
}
```

I am sharing this config file and definitions file as it was impossible to figure it out from the RabbitMQ web site.

Note: This config worked on RabbitMQ 3.6.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 14):

To add more details to [IvanD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36930931), this is how I did it.

First: `sudo nano /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` (this command might be different depending on your OS)

```
[
  {rabbit,
    [
        {default_vhost,<<"/">>},
        {default_user,<<"someuser">>},
        {default_pass,<<"somepassword">>},
        {default_permissions, [<<".*">>, <<".*">>, <<".*">>]},
        {default_user_tags, [administrator]}
    ]
  },
  {rabbitmq_management,
    [{listener, [{port, 15672}]},
        {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json"},
        {http_log_dir, "/var/log/rabbitmq/management_http.log"}]
  }
].
```

Then create the additional json: `sudo nano /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json` (this command might be different depending on your OS).
Its content:

```js
{
  "vhosts":[
        {"name":"/"}
  ],
  "policies":[
        {"vhost":"/","name":"ha","pattern":"", "definition":{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic","ha-sync-batch-size":5}}
  ]
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: The ha-sync-batch-size is only supported in RabbitMQ versions above 3.6.0! https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#sync-batch-size
If your Rabbit is older than that, remove the setting from the `rabbitmq_definitions.json`.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty and RabbitMQ v.3.6.2.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, You can load policies, queues, exchanges, bindings, users and much more directly on restart using [definition import at load time](https://www.rabbitmq.com/definitions.html#import-on-boot)**.

1. #### Preconfigure you Rabbit

   Go to `http://localhost:15672` Admin -> Policies page and create a new policy you need:

   [image: Creating new policy]

   You may also preconfigure queues and other things.
2. #### Dump definitions

   `curl -s -H "Accept:application/json" -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/definitions > definitions.json`

   You can also dump your definitions using web interface. Open Overview tab, scroll down:

   [image: Downloading definitions]

   (!!!) Alter `definitions.json`, so as to keep things you need on restart only.

   There will be section withing your policies, keep it:

   ```
   ...
   "policies": [
     {
       "vhost": "/",
       "name": "ha-all",
       "pattern": "",
       "apply-to": "all",
       "definition": {
         "ha-mode": "all"
       },
       "priority": 0
     }
   ]
   ...
   ```
3. #### Load definitions on restart

   Put that `definitions.json` nearby your rabbit and add this line to `rabbit.conf`. No need to use old format:

   ```
   management.load_definitions = /path/to/definitions.json
   ```

So as to load something after restart use [cli tools](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cli.html).

---

Paying tribute to @IvanD since my answer is pretty much the same as [his own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36930931/4175647) but reveals detailed steps and new config format usage. Not enough space in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Policy can't be set in the `rabbitmq.config` file.  One workaround is to start rmq using an init script and put the `rabbitmqctl` command inside there so that it is run whenever rmq starts or restarts.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found something which worked:
No need of configMap or rabbitmq.config files.
Under

```
containers:
...
...
...

    lifecycle:
              postStart:
                exec:
                  command: ["/bin/sh","-c","rabbitmq-plugins --offline enable rabbitmq_management;until rabbitmqctl node_health_check; do  sleep 5;done;rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all \".\" '{\"ha-mode\":\"all\", \"ha-sync-mode\":\"automatic\"}' --apply-to all --priority 0;"]
```